# Binary write to address

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

Can someone help me out writing hex string to file hex address from textbox?

This is my current code:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    BinaryWriter wr = new BinaryWriter(File.OpenWrite(listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString()));       
    for (int i = 0x83C410; i <= 0x83C417; i++)
    {
        wr.Write(textBox1.Text);
    }
    wr.Close();       
}
```

But it doesn't work after i click button nothing happens to file, even it doesn't show any error which is kinda strange.

After few tweaks i got it working saving value into file binary but now it add one extra char idk how. This is code i use now:

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        BinaryWriter wr = new BinaryWriter(File.OpenWrite(listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString()));
        wr.BaseStream.Position = 0x83C410;
        wr.Write(textBox1.Text);
        wr.Flush();
    }
```

Instead adding 8 bytes it adds 9 1 extra, and my textbox is limited to 8 chars.
Hex that adds: 08736574706F777265
Instead: 736574706F777265
ASCII that adds: .setpowre
Instead: setpowre

Comment: I dont understand. do you want to convert integer to hex and then save it?

Comment: It gets hard to guess at the intent when code is so completely incapable of doing what is intended.  Starting points are FileStream.Seek() and Encoding.GetBytes().

Comment: What if you add `FileMode.Create` as a second argument when you create the `BinaryWriter`?

Comment: @HansPassant okay let me try to explain.. I have managed to read hex value from file and convert it to ascii and show in textbox. Now i want to edit text in textbox and to save it back to file? Hope you guys understand like this? Sorry for my english :/

Comment: Why are you storing hex strings in files? Do you know about binary data? And no, we don't understand this at all. Because it is very unclear. Please try to explain by editing the question.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan i provided source code and screenshot :)

Comment: Well, if you say that we should be able to understand it, so be it.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan here is it once again for you http://pastebin.com/Lxf5aLXm

It would be really nice if you could help me with snippet getting save option working :)

Comment: It would be really nice if you could make the question clearer. Once again, one can only wonder why you feel compelled to convert perfectly good binary into hex strings. Usually people do that when they don't understand the difference between binary and text. It's absolutely not acceptable to ask your question in comments. If you've got detail to add, you must edit the question.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan come to teamviewer i will show you: 628 694 210 pw:ew27v6 

Please?

Comment: You have completely failed to understand what Stack Overflow is about. It's as if you did not read my comments. Your next move is to read the help section of the website to learn what makes a good question. Stack Overflow is not a place where you get people to do your work for you. If you need that kind of help you are in the wrong place.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan updated main...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            BinaryWriter wr = new BinaryWriter(File.OpenWrite(listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString()));
            wr.BaseStream.Position = 0x83C410;
            wr.Write(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(textBox1.Text));
            wr.Close();
        }
```

This is answer to my question.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, a few hints when using FileWriters:

- Always put them within using-statements when possible, so they get properly disposed of.
- I always recommend calling `Flush()` explicitly instead of `Close()`. The `Dispose()`-method will close it afterwards anyway, and Closing does not always Flush the writer. This might be the cause why your writes aren't being flushed to the file.

Another interesting point about your code is that you are using a for-loop with specific hexadecimal values, only to write the same value (`textBox1.Text`) to the file. Why is that?

Update - I saw your code at flushbin, and if you don't mind, I picked out this part where you commented out some other code:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
#region "New"
            //byte[] bytes = new byte[str.Length * sizeof(char)];
            //System.Buffer.BlockCopy(textBox1.Text.ToCharArray(), 0, bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
            //using (FileStream fs = File.OpenWrite(listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString()))
            //{
            //    fs.Seek(0x83C410, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            //    fs.Write(bytes, 0, 7);
            //}
#endregion

            BinaryWriter wr = new BinaryWriter(File.OpenWrite(listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString()));
            textBox8.Text = ConvertToHex(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(textBox8.Text));
            for (int i = 0x83C410; i <= 0x83C417; i++)
            {

               // wr.Write(textBox1.Text);
            }
            wr.Close();
        }
```

My point about using the using-statement and calling Flush() explicitly still stands, but now I see that when you are *reading* the file you are using the hexadecimal values of the for-loop to determine the stream-position of the bytes to read, so I guess you should not forget to use these numbers to explicitly set the stream-position when you are *writing* the bytes:

```
wr.BaseStream.Position = i;
```

Another difference is that you are reading byte for byte, whereas you are writing the entire string at once, so you either do not need the for-loop in your write-method, or you should change your code to writing byte for byte too.

Comment: I have 8 values, i read them from file to textbox1,textbox2.. etc
So each value has its locked address else file will get corrupted. If needed i could somehow show whole source maybe teamviewer?

Comment: @user3385780: Couldn't you edit your post to show all the code necessary? That would make it a lot easier for us to answer your question. :)

Comment: Its pretty long and messed :/ i can put it in pastebin?

Comment: Can you help me with it? Please?

Comment: I added `wr.BaseStream.Position = i;` but still nothing happens with file

Answer (score 0):

Since `Listbox.SelectedItem` is an `Object`, the `ToString()` method will probably not return the value you want it it return. Try this instead;

```
string selected = listBox1.GetItemText(listBox1.SelectedValue);
BinaryWriter bw = new BinaryWriter(File.OpenWrite(selected));
```

Comment: He is trying to read and write a value from a TextBox, not a ListBox :)

Comment: He is selecting the files from a listbox I figured. Either that or his naming skills are terrible.

Comment: It drops now error, `cannot convert from 'string' to 'System.IO.Stream'`.
I think problem is in:
`for (int i = 0x83C410; i <= 0x83C417; i++)
    {
        wr.Write(textBox1.Text);
    }`
So if anyone have solution for it please?

Comment: Im selecting file from listBox and value i want to input in file is from textBox :) @Wim.van.Gool

Comment: That is because I incindentally forgot `File.OpenWrite()`. I fixed it already.

Comment: @DionV. error on button click in debug `Empty path name is not legal.`